# Power Apps Portal - Entity List Column Name Override

Tags: powerapps-portal

Does anyone know the liquid template variable name for using the column name override instead of the name defined in the view?

```
<th width="{{ c.width }}" class="govuk-table__header" data-logicalname="{{ c.logical_name }}">
    {% if c.sort_enabled %}
        {% assign current_sort = order | current_sort:c.logical_name %}
        {% case current_sort %}
            {% when 'ASC' %}
                <a href="{{ request.path_and_query | add_query:'order', c.sort_descending }}"><i class="fa fa-sort-asc"></i>
                {{ c.name }}
                </a>
                {% when 'DESC' %}
                <a href="{{ request.path_and_query | add_query:'order', c.sort_ascending }}"><i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i>
                {{ c.name }}
                </a>
                {% else %}
                <a href="{{ request.path_and_query | add_query:'order', c.sort_ascending }}"><i class="fa fa-sort-desc fa-rotate-270"></i>
                {{ c.name }}
                </a>
            {% endcase %}
    {% else %}
        {{ c.name }}
    {% endif %}
</th>
```

I'm currently using `c.name` but I want the name to inherit the column name attribute in the entity list configuration.

Answer (score 0):

ASAIK this isn't possible, you need to add the logic to the template to rename the column name, see 'XXXXXXXXXX' below:

```
{% if c.logical_name == "XXXXXXXXXX" %}


<th width="{{ c.width }}" class="govuk-table__header" data-logicalname="{{ c.logical_name }}">
    {% if c.sort_enabled %}
        {% assign current_sort = order | current_sort:c.logical_name %}
        {% case current_sort %}
            {% when 'ASC' %}
                <a href="{{ request.path_and_query | add_query:'order', c.sort_descending }}"><i class="fa fa-sort-asc"></i>
                XXXXXXXXXX
                </a>
                {% when 'DESC' %}
                <a href="{{ request.path_and_query | add_query:'order', c.sort_ascending }}"><i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i>
                XXXXXXXXXX
                </a>
                {% else %}
                <a href="{{ request.path_and_query | add_query:'order', c.sort_ascending }}"><i class="fa fa-sort-desc fa-rotate-270"></i>
                XXXXXXXXXX
                </a>
            {% endcase %}
    {% else %}
        {{ c.name }}
    {% endif %}
</th>
{% else %}
<th width="{{ c.width }}" class="govuk-table__header" data-logicalname="{{ c.logical_name }}">
    {% if c.sort_enabled %}
        {% assign current_sort = order | current_sort:c.logical_name %}
        {% case current_sort %}
            {% when 'ASC' %}
                <a href="{{ request.path_and_query | add_query:'order', c.sort_descending }}"><i class="fa fa-sort-asc"></i>
                {{ c.name }}
                </a>
                {% when 'DESC' %}
                <a href="{{ request.path_and_query | add_query:'order', c.sort_ascending }}"><i class="fa fa-sort-desc"></i>
                {{ c.name }}
                </a>
                {% else %}
                <a href="{{ request.path_and_query | add_query:'order', c.sort_ascending }}"><i class="fa fa-sort-desc fa-rotate-270"></i>
                {{ c.name }}
                </a>
            {% endcase %}
    {% else %}
        {{ c.name }}
    {% endif %}
</th>
{% endif %}
```